# What is the earliest reference of the seven sacraments in the Orthodox Church?

Tags: church-history, eastern-orthodox, sacraments

In the Roman-Catholic Church, the earliest writings that explicitly mention the seven sacraments come from Peter Lombard’s “Setences”.

I am curious what are the earliest reference in Eastern-Orthodoxy towards these sacraments and if the Catholic Church had an influence in the development of these terms, on Estern-Orthodoxy.

Comment: Do you have a reference/link to the relevant section in Peter Lombard's "Setences"?  Also,  does that source provide a date with regard to the Roman Catholic Church sacraments?

Comment: Lombard, *Sentences* IV, d. 1, c. 4, a. 2, 233. Lombard identified seven sacraments: Baptism, Eucharist, Confirmation, Marriage, Ordination, Confession (Penance), and Extreme Unction.